# Left Join not showing null records in Active Record Yii

Tags: mysql, sql, join, yii, left-join

I know this question may be asked earlier and I have applied fixes mentioned there but they are not working.

Here is my problem:

I have two tables that I want to join and get the results.

1. task (id, status,task_type_id)
2. task_type (id, task_type_name)

There is one to many relationship between task_type to task.

My requirement:

I want to get all the tasks the user has created grouped by their task_type_id and currently incomplete.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select = "t.*, t2.task_type_id,count(t2.task_type_id) as total";
    $criteria->join = "LEFT JOIN task t2 on t.id=t2.task_type_id";
    $criteria->condition = "t.user_id=" . $user_id . " OR t.user_id is NULL";
    $criteria->addCondition("t2.user_id=" . $user_id);
    $criteria->addCondition("t2.status='Incomplete'");
    $criteria->group = "t.id";
    $criteria->order = 'total desc';
    $task_types = TaskType::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

It returns everything correct but the null values of task_type tables are not shown. i.e it shows only those task_type for which a task does exist. It does not show the task_type for which the task_type does not exist. I want all the task_types either for which the task exist or not.

Can someone sugggest a fix? I have used the left join which should return both types of task_types but its not working.

Comment: Looks like you need to use LEFT JOIN and change WHERE into AND

Comment: already used the LEFT JOIN and where to change 'where' ? the condition property is translated to where in active record

Answer (score 0):

Update following with later statement

```
$criteria->condition = "t.user_id=" . $user_id . " OR t.user_id is NULL";

$criteria->condition = "COALESCE(t.user_id,1)=" . COALESCE($user_id,1). ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditions on t2 are activated after the left join.  Change them to part of the Left Join On clause, so if they are not met, they won't remove the record from the data set.